# Saving Array to Chrome Local Storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I am saving an array to local storage and then adding the words in the array to a `ul` on the popup.html page I am using in a chrome extension I am writing.

Problem is after I leave the popup.html the keywords that I save to local storage no longer appear in the form.

This leads me to believe I am not saving them to local storage.

Am I saving the array correctly and calling the keywords stored in the array inside local storage correctly?

```
  keyWordArray = [];
keyWords = $('#keyWords').html();
keyWordArray = localStorage.keyWords;

keyIn = localStorage.setItem("keyWords", JSON.stringify(keyWordArray));
keyOut= JSON.parse(keyWordArray);

Description = $('#description').val();

loadKeys = function loadKeyWords() {
  //clear the existing data
  $('#keyWords').html('');
    //for all the items in the array...
    for(var i = 0; i < keyOut.length; i++) {
      //add them to the UL
      $('#keyWords').append('<li><input id="check" name="check" type="checkbox">'+keyWordArray[i]+'</li>'); 
        }
    };

$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#add').click( function() {

    if($(Description) === '') {
      $('#alert').html("<strong>Warning!</strong> Enter some things you hate!");
      $('#alert').fadeIn().delay(1000).fadeOut();
      return false;
    }

    //add the new keyword to the array
    keyWordArray.push(Description);
    //overwrite the array in localStorage with the new, updated array
    keyIn();
    //call loadKeyWords() to rebuild the UL and hide any matching elements
    loadKeys();
    return false;
  });

  $('#clear').click( function() {
    window.localStorage.clear();
    location.reload();
    return false;
  });

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var page = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
    // now you can access the background page objects / functions
      for(var i = 0; i < keyWordArray.length; i++) {
      //and hide any DOM elements that have the keyword
      $("div:contains('"+keyWordArray[i]+"')").hide();    
        }
    });

loadKeys();
}); //end of document ready function
```

Comment: I believe localstorage only accepts key value pairs, which is perhaps why it is not saving the array directly. Perhaps try using ``localStorage.keyWords =keyWordArray`` or ```localStorage.setItem("keyWords", keyWordArray)```

Comment: Ok I think your right from what I read. JS is not my strongest. Are you saying add the line and it should fix my program or change everywhere I mention local storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that is out of context of your problem that explicitly saves an array to local storage:

```
// set up the array
var theArray = ['red', 'green', 'blue'],
    localStorageTheArray;

// convert the array to a string and write it to local storage 
localStorage.setItem('theArray', JSON.stringify(theArray));

// retrieve the string from local storage and convert it back to an array
localStorageTheArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('theArray'));

localStorageTheArray.push('purple');

console.log(localStorageTheArray);
// ["red", "green", "blue", "purple"]
```

Link to [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ianjamieson/01eLct37/)

**Example with functions**

```
function setArrayInLocalStorage(key, array) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(array));
}

function getArrayInLocalStorage(key) {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
}

// to set
setArrayInLocalStorage('theArray', theArray);

// to get
getArrayInLocalStorage('theArray');
```

Comment: So in this example is theArray also the key in the local storage.  so for me if I had the key as keyword and the array as myArray would it then be,
localStorage.setItem('keyword', JSON.stringify(myArray)); ?

Comment: Yes, correct. You would then retrieve that key, `localStorageTheArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('keyword'));`

Comment: So after you consolo.log at the end there can I just push to the array and print the array without ever calling the stringifya nd parse again? Does it just need to be done once after it's created? Or do I need to think of it as something moving back and forth and needs to be converted each time?

Comment: You need to convert it every single time. Every time you write to local storage you will need to stringify and every time you will need to parse. I have written a function that would be able to do this for you each time.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`localStorage["keyWords"] = JSON.stringify(keyWordArray);`

with:

`localStorage.setItem("keyWords", JSON.stringify(keyWordArray));`

And then when accessing the keywords use:

`localStorage.keyWords`

instead of:

`localStorage["keyWords"]`

Can't guarantee that will fix all of your problems but it should solve the local storage issue.

Comment: When I updated my code it wont take any new value and display them but it dit add these values to local storage and display it till I delete it. [
"
d
e
2
d
"
,
"
d
e
2
d
"
,
"
d
e
2
d
"
,
"
d
e
2
d
"
]

Comment: I updated my code if you dont mind checking for me. Also thank you for your help.

Comment: what do you mean by "it won't take any new value and display them"

Comment: When I try to add a new keyword to the array it does not display it, it only shows me the de2d thing. I am printing a list of the keywords I am adding to local storage to the screen in a ul.

Comment: I changed the code so I updated it. I created the statements you gave me in the global scope. Now I can add new keywords to local storage and it shows them on the screen being added but instead of the keywords I am adding they appears as symbols,  But I must be close because something is being entered for sure because its displaying most symbols to the screen. Looks like this,

\
"
\
\
\
"
\
\
\
\
\
\
\
"
\
\
\
\
\
\
\
\
\